# How to give custom name to Time Machine backup

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup

I have used Clonezilla when I was a windows and linux user. I really liked how Clonezilla allows you to rename your backup to anything. It is possible to do so during Time Machine backup? I want to name my backups so I might not flash something else that I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time Machine does not allow to provide a name for a backup.  You can name the drive when directly attached, but not the backups within.

> I want to name my backups so I might not flash something else that I
>   don't want.

Not entirely sure what you mean by that, but if you meant backing up items already backed up, then you will need to understand that Time Machine is an incremental backup system and does that for you automatically.

The following official document (and its links) may shed some light on this as well: [Mac Basics: Time Machine backs up your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250)